# How to override Win 10 cursor size?

Tags: windows, mouse

So I have a sight impaired uncle who can no longer see the mouse, even at the largest setting. Is there a way in the Win 10 API or maybe the Registry to make the cursor size much bigger?

He obviously needs to use it across all apps and I haven't really used the Win 10 API so I'm not sure where to start or even if it's possible?

Would this be possible to do in Python or would I have to use C#?

Thanks.

Comment: I would go for a `reg` command...

Answer (score 0):

Try going to Cursor Size in the Control Panel.
As far as i know. It allows you to push the cursor to quite the size.